# vue.js 3 insert images in table header

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm using a vue.js 3 v-data-table and want to insert images in the table header.
Therefore I'm trying to overwrite the table header template:

```html
<template v-for="header in headers" v-slot:[`header.${header.value}`]="{ headers }">        

     {{ header.text }}

</template>
```

This works. However, there is an error if I include the pictures like this:

```html
<template v-for="header in headers" v-slot:[`header.${header.value}`]="{ headers }">
    {{ header.text }}
    <span v-if="header.text=='SomeText'"><img :src="require('@/assets/image_1.png')" /></span>
    <span v-if="header.text=='SomeOtherText'"><img :src="require('@/assets/image_2.png')" /></span>
</template>
```

The error is:

```
14:3  error  Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives  vue/require-v-for-key
```

I would be happy if someone can provide an advice.

Answer (score 1):

Try to key the nested elements based on the index of the current header :

```
<template v-for="(header,i) in headers" v-slot:[`header.${header.value}`]="{ headers }">
    <span :key="'text'+i"> {{ header.text }}</span>
    <span :key="'img1'+i" v-if="header.text=='SomeText'"><img :src="require('@/assets/image_1.png')" /></span>
    <span :key="'img2'+i" v-if="header.text=='SomeOtherText'"><img :src="require('@/assets/image_2.png')" /></span>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`vue/require-v-for-key` docs](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/require-v-for-key.html#rule-details) show an example of how to address the issue:

```html
<template>
  <!-- ✓ GOOD -->
  <div
    v-for="todo in todos"
    :key="todo.id"
  />
  <!-- ✗ BAD -->
  <div v-for="todo in todos"/>
</template>
```

A unique [`key` attribute](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/special-attributes.html#key) is needed for each element in `v-for` for proper rendering, especially if the element order can change.

In your case, you could use `header.value` as the `key` on the `<template>`:

```html
<template v-for="header in headers"
          v-slot:[`header.${header.value}`]="{ headers }"
         :key="header.value">
```

*`header.value` is assumed to be unique here, as required by `v-slot`. Otherwise, you'd see a different lint error ([`vue/valid-v-slot`](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/valid-v-slot.html)).*